# Loading WMS/WMTS on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wmts

[image]The Sinca WMTS service works great on QGIS 2.18 but you can not connect to it on QGIS 3.1.

http://gis.sinica.edu.tw/worldmap/wmts

When I try to connect to it on QGIS 3.2.2 I get an error saying "failed to download capabilities". When I connect to it on QGIS 2.18 it works perfectly

Is anyone else experiencing this and has anyone found a solution?

I have attached a screenshot of my network settings.

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: When I try to connect to it on QGIS 3.2.2 I get an error saying "failed to download capabilities". When I connect to it on QGIS 2.18 it works perfectly.

Comment: please edit the question

Comment: and then check your network settings

Comment: Works for me with QGIS 3.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this direct [WMTS Capabilities XML](http://gis.sinica.edu.tw/worldmap/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml) URL Link instead of the http://gis.sinica.edu.tw/worldmap/wmts